# php - how to combine every single component of a number between some letters randomly and in order

Tags: php

i want to send user id with the url to another page but for hiden it from the user i want to distribute the number in string letters and remove the letters in other page but i dont know how to add numbers in letters randomly but in order?
something like this:
letters:

```
$Letters="aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

user id:

```
$id=12345
```

i want numbers added to the letters randomly but in order like this:

```
aa1aa2aa34aaaa5aaa
```

or

```
a1aaaaa2aaaa3aa4a5
```

or

```
1aaaa23aaa4aaaa5aa
```

and... 
i try this code but it doesnt works:

```
substr_replace('aaaaaaaaaaaaa','12345',1,0);
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you feel the need to hide the ID?

Comment: because user cant find our of other users id and...!

Comment: Why not? What does finding out the ID enable other users to do? If that is enough to compromise your application, then you need to implement some serious security.

Comment: @El_Vanja i am creating a website. what kind of security can I make ?

Comment: That question is too broad to be answered. But generally, user ID is not something that needs to be hidden. What you really need to hide are operations the user can perform. That's why login exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is sample code to achieve your requirement:

```
$letters=str_split("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
shuffle($letters);
$letters = implode('', $letters);

$id=12345;
$userId = str_split((string)$id);
$end = strlen($letters);
$start = 0;

foreach ($userId as $value) {
    $start += rand(0,5)+1;
    $letters = substr_replace($letters, $value, $start, 0);
}

print $letters;
```

this will give output like

```
abcd1efgh2ijk3lmnop4qrst5uvwxyz
```

or

```
lp1finbd2cwkzh3t4soeq5jmuvrgxya
```